# SQL Group by colum1 "keep" by datetime

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, greatest-n-per-group

I have the follow table:

```
ID  --  timestamps  -- uid
 1  --    12:00     --  1
 2  --    12:15     --  1
 3  --    12:30     --  2
 4  --    12:45     --  2
```

Now I need unique uid's by the last timestamps, result have to look like this:

```
ID  --  timestamps  -- uid
 2  --    12:15     --  1
 4  --    12:45     --  2
```

If there is any problem with joins, tell me please.
Thats my current SQL Statmant:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "lists".* FROM "lists" INNER JOIN identifys i WHERE (i.ip
= '1' OR i.session = '2')
```

And that my ActiveRecord:

```
List.all.joins("INNER JOIN identifys i")
    .where("i.ip = ? OR i.session = ?", ip, session)
    .distinct
```

Answer (score 2):

How about adding `Group by`  to your query? Something along these lines:

```
select Max(l.ID) as ID, Max(l.timestamps) as timestamps, l.uid
from Lists l INNER JOIN identifys i 
WHERE (i.ip = '1' OR i.session = '2')
Group By l.uid
```

Another possible solution:

```
  SELECT l2.id , a.uid, a.timestamps
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT  Max(l.timestamps) as timestamps, l.uid
    FROM Lists l INNER JOIN identifys i 
    WHERE (i.ip = '1' OR i.session = '2')
    Group By l.uid
  ) a 
    Inner Join Lists l2 on a.timestamps = l2.timestamps
```

Comment: This would fail if `ID` does not strictly increase as `timestamp` gets larger

Comment: @Andomar, thats true, did try it

Comment: since there was no `sql` standard specified, I tied to provide generic solution...

Comment: replace Max(l.ID) with l.ID and its work perfect ... :)

Comment: the problem is that you're not guaranteed always the highest value for the ID if you do so...

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL or SQLite you could use a filtering join, like:

```
select  *
from    YourTable yt
join    (
        select  UID
        ,       max(timestamp) as max_timestamp
        from    YourTable
        group by
                UID
        ) filter
on      yt.UID = filter.UID
        and yt.timestamp = filter.max_timestamp
```

In a datase that supports windowing functions, like PostgreSQL, Oracle or SQL Server, you could:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() (
                    partition by UID
                    order by timestamp desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- Only latest row per UID
```